# How to properly decode AWS Kinesis stream data aside from utf-8 and latin-1

Tags: json, aws-lambda, utf-8, decode, amazon-kinesis

I'm currently working with a Kinesis stream that I am trying to parse data from. I have no knowledge of the data being streamed or the format of it, so I am trying to find that out. I need to know the format of the data, so I set up a Lambda function that has the following code:

```
import json
import base64

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        # print("UTF-8 decoded data :", base64.b64decode(record['kinesis']['data']).decode('utf-8')
        print("Latin-1 decoded data :", base64.b64decode(record['kinesis']['data']).decode('latin-1')
```

As you can see, I originally was decoding the data using utf-8, but I was getting this error: `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xda in position 0: invalid continuation byte`.

I read another post on here that said to decode using latin-1 instead, which is what I am currently trying. The data is now being output to CloudWatch logs, but I am getting strange characters in the output as such:

```
Latin-1 decoded data: Ú ÚË
   {
       <key-value pairs being printed here>
   }
   Ü Æ
   {
       <more data being printed here>
   }
   Ù vŪĘ
   {
       <more data here>
   }
```

As you can see, I am getting these strange characters before every key-value mapping. How can I properly decode the data to get the data without these strange characters?

Comment: Double checking: There is a syntax error in the code sample. There's no closing paren `)`, so it's ambiguous if `base64.b64decode()` is called on `record['kinesis']['data']` or `record['kinesis']['data'].decode('utf-8')`. To clarify, `base64.b64decode()` should be called on `record['kinesis']['data']` first and `decode('utf-8')` after.

Comment: Yes I forgot to add it when I was writing this post, I have it properly written in the actual code.

Comment: Often this issue occurs if the character encoding is different at the source level. Are you sure, that it is encoded with `UTF-8` or `latin-1` encoding?